# Is there a way to specify how many characters of a string to print out using printf()?

Tags: c++, c, printf

Is there a way to specify how many characters of a string to print out (similar to decimal places in `int`s)?

```
printf ("Here are the first 8 chars: %s\n", "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

Would like it to print: `Here are the first 8 chars: A string`

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The basic way is:

```
printf ("Here are the first 8 chars: %.8s\n", "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

The other, often more useful, way is:

```
printf ("Here are the first %d chars: %.*s\n", 8, 8, "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

Here, you specify the length as an int argument to printf(), which treats the '*' in the format as a request to get the length from an argument.

You can also use the notation:

```
printf ("Here are the first 8 chars: %*.*s\n",
        8, 8, "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

This is also analogous to the "%8.8s" notation, but again allows you to specify the minimum and maximum lengths at runtime - more realistically in a scenario like:

```
printf("Data: %*.*s Other info: %d\n", minlen, maxlen, string, info);
```

The POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) defines these mechanisms.

Comment: To the last example: What if copied string is shorter than minlen?

Comment: The output will be blank padded (on the left unless you add a `-`) to make it up to the full specified length.

Comment: This is awesome trick if one wants to use `std::string_view` in `C` context without promotion to `std::string`.

Comment: Unfortunately the printf() is unbalanced. It only fills up with spaces on the left side if string is right aligned, but if string is left aligned (by a '-') it doesn't fill up with spaces :-(

Comment: @Jesko: Are you looking for `printf("[%-8.8s] [%8.8s]\n", "hello", "hello");`?  The first blank-pads on the right; the second on the left.

Comment: What are types of `minlen` and `maxlen`? Are they `int` or `size_t`? It's important, because can result in UB.

Comment: @273K: the types of the values passed for `*` values in `printf()` are of type `int` and not `size_t`.  This is largely a legacy design decision — `size_t` didn't exist when the Standard I/O library was created back in the late 70s.  If you were redesigning the library and still used the `*` symbols, they'd probably be `ssize_t` (the signed analogue of `size_t`) since you can use `-8` to indicate that the string should be left justified (and `+8` to indicate right justification).  Or you might decide that `int` is quite big enough (even if it is a 16-bit type) and keep `int` as the type.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to specify a fixed amount of characters, you can also use `*` which means that printf takes the number of characters from an argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char hello[] = "Hello world";
    printf("message: '%.3s'\n", hello);
    printf("message: '%.*s'\n", 3, hello);
    printf("message: '%.*s'\n", 5, hello);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
message: 'Hel'
message: 'Hel'
message: 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 17):

```
printf ("Here are the first 8 chars: %.8s\n", "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

%8s would specify a minimum width of 8 characters. You want to truncate at 8, so use %.8s.

If you want to always print exactly 8 characters you could use %8.8s

Answer (score 12):

Using `printf` you can do

```
printf("Here are the first 8 chars: %.8s\n", "A string that is more than 8 chars");
```

If you're using C++, you can achieve the same result using the STL:

```
using namespace std; // for clarity
string s("A string that is more than 8 chars");
cout << "Here are the first 8 chars: ";
copy(s.begin(), s.begin() + 8, ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
cout << endl;
```

Or, less efficiently:

```
cout << "Here are the first 8 chars: " <<
        string(s.begin(), s.begin() + 8) << endl;
```

Comment: Note: do **not** use `ostream_iterator<char>(cout)`! Instead, use `ostreambuf_iterator<char>(cout)`! The difference in performance should be rather large.

Comment: Way more efficient to instead use: [`std::cout.write(s.data(), 8)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). Or in modern C++, `std::cout << std::string_view{s.data(), 8}`.

Answer (score 5):

printf(....."%.8s")

Answer (score 4):

In C++ it is easy.

```
std::copy(someStr.c_str(), someStr.c_str()+n, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
```

EDIT:
It is also safer to use this with string iterators, so you don't run off the end. I'm not sure what happens with printf and string that are too short, but I'm guess this may be safer.

Comment: ha, yeah that's "easy". C++ always looks like car accident.

Comment: you still can do printf() in c++ :)

Comment: I think this was sarcasm. `std::cout << someStr.substr(0,8);` is far more obvious.

Comment: @MSalters You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Print first four characters:

`printf("%.4s\n", "A string that is more than 8 chars");`

See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for more information (check .precision -section)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, I do it in this way:

```
char *buffer = "My house is nice";
string showMsgStr(buffer, buffer + 5);
std::cout << showMsgStr << std::endl;
```

Please note this is not safe because when passing the second argument I can go beyond the size of the string and generate a memory access violation. You have to implement your own check for avoiding this.