# printf string, variable length item

Tags: c, format, printf

```
#define SIZE 9
int number=5;
char letters[SIZE]; /* this wont be null-terminated */
... 

char fmt_string[20];
sprintf(fmt_string, "%%d %%%ds", SIZE);
/* fmt_string = "%d %9d"... or it should be */

printf(fmt_string, number, letters);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be building a format string. But you should be assigning the string returned by `sprintf` to `fmt_string` and `fmt_string` shouldn't be in the parameter list.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you say that `letters` won't be null-terminated?

Comment: @AndrewKeeton this was for a search problem with a large dataset where I couldn't afford the space to hold null characters.

Comment: NOTE: this is a duplicity of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239519/is-there-a-way-to-specify-how-many-characters-of-a-string-to-print-out-using-pri

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is no need to construct a special format string.  `printf` allows you to specify the precision using a parameter (that precedes the value) if you use a `.*` as the precision in the format tag.

For example:

```
printf ("%d %.*s", number, SIZE, letters);
```

Note: there is a distinction between width (which is a minimum field width) and precision (which gives the maximum number of characters to be printed).
`%*s` specifies the width, `%.s` specifies the precision. (and you can also use `%*.*` but then you need two parameters, one for the width one for the precision)

See also the printf man page ([`man 3 printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) under Linux) and especially the sections on field width and precision:

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some
>   decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the next
>   argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type int.

Comment: Had them mixed up... scanf is the one that doesn't have that option.

Comment: It also works with 2 lengths like `"%*.*s", minlength, maxlength, letters`.

Comment: Note: `"*m$"` is not standard C.

Comment: Is there a way to get the "%.*s" format to accept `size_t` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 6):

A somewhat unknown function is [`asprintf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Output.html#index-asprintf).  The first parameter is a `**char`.  This function will `malloc` space for the string so you don't have to do the bookkeeping.  Remember to `free` the string when done.

```
char *fmt_string;

asprintf(&fmt_string, "%%d %%%ds", SIZE);
printf(fmt_string, number, letters);
free(fmt_string);
```

is an example of use.

Comment: Although asprintf is indeed an interesting function, it is important to note that it is a gnu extention.  Also, I'm not sure how this addresses the question.

Comment: @Trent, it's true that it started as a GNU extension, but in the mean time [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/asprintf.3), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=asprintf) and [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?asprintf) have implemented it. Even [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asprintf.3.html) has it now.