# Print one word from string

Tags: c

I want to print for example third word from some string.

In example below - it works, but - can it be made other, better, way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char str1[20] = "This is string";
int a, b = 0, nums = 1;
char sec[20];

int main()
{
    for (a = 0; a <= strlen(str1); a++) {

        if ( str1[a] != ' ')
        {
            printf ("%c", str1[a]);

           if (nums == 3)
            {
                sec[b] = str1[a];
                ++b;
            }

        } else {
            printf ("\n");
            ++nums;
        }
    }

    printf ("\n\n%s\n", str1);
    printf ("Total words count: %d\n", nums);

    printf("Third word: %s\n", sec);

    return 0;

}
```

May be - with `*pointers`, instead of `arrays[]`, or something else?

Also - is it good idea to use nested `if` operators in **C**?

Comment: Iterating with strlen is bad. in "for (a = 0; a <= strlen(str1); a++)" It will rescan the whole string on each loop.

Comment: Probably a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can use printf length limiters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239519/is-there-a-way-to-specify-how-many-characters-of-a-string-to-print-out-using-pri

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution, but you could use [strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm). Assuming that all your words are separated by spaces, then it is just a matter of strtok'ing x number of times. I just threw this thing together real quick, but it should work OK, I hope.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char str[] = "This is a string\n";
    char *token;
    int i;
    token = strtok( str, " ");
    i = 1;
    while( token != NULL ) {
        if( 3 == i ) {
            fprintf( stdout, "%s\n", token );
            fflush( stdout );
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;  // <-- this was missing
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note that strtok is changing the original string. you need to duplicate it before calling strtok.

Comment: You're missing an `i++` in the loop.  Tried to edit, but my edit is awaiting peer review.

Comment: That's true. Only use strtok() when you have no more use for the original string, or copy it to some temporary variable and only work of off that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"%n` to locate the ends of the sub-string being sought.

No modifications or copying of the source string are needed.

```
void Print_Nth_word(const char *s, unsigned n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    int left;
    int right;
    while (1) {
      left = right = 0;
      sscanf(s, " %n%*s%n", &left, &right);
      if (right <= left) return;  // no sub-string (word) found
      if (--n == 0) break;
      s += right;
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", right - left, &s[left]);
  }
}
```

`" %n%*s%n"` detail:
`" "` Skip white space.
`"%n"` Save offset of current scanning.
`"*s"` Scan, but do not save non-whitespace.  (a word)

`"%.*s", right - left, &s[left]` detail: Print `&s[left]` up to  `right - left` characters.