# how Printf stmt perform printf("%*.*s",10,7,str); in detailed explanation

Tags: c, printf

Why we used *.* while printing the string.

```cpp
    printf("%*.*s",10,7,str);
```

This is the actual program. how the printf statement preforms the operation in detailed explanation.

```cpp
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    { 
    char *str="c-pointer";
    printf("%*.*s",10,7,str); 
    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, This answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2239571/6400614

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%*.*s",10,7,str);
```

equal to

```
printf("%10.7s",str);
```

You tell to printf to print minimum 10 Letter and first 7 characters in str, so

```
"   c-point"
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The character to fill is space and default justification is right.

And you can change justify to left by

```
printf("%-10.7s",str);
```

it will print

```
"c-point   "
```

and you can not add `0` to `%s` but you can do this in numeric conversions and you can not use both `-` and `0` in numeric conversions also because `-` will override `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The .7 is a *precision*

Read no more the 7 characters from `str`.

---

The 10 is a minimum *width*

Print at least 10 characters, pad if needed.