# Print (work with) substrings in a C program

Tags: c, printf, substring, c-strings, function-definition

How do I work with a string if I only want to print part of it?

For example, print `"bcd"` from `"abcdef"`?

I know how to work with a pointer to the beginning of a string, but I don't know how to determine the end.

```
void vypis(char *retezec)
{   
    printf("%s", retezec);
}

int main (void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t capacity;
        
    getline(&str, &capacity, stdin);    
    vypis(str);
    vypis(str+1);       
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to specify how many characters of a string to print out using printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239519/is-there-a-way-to-specify-how-many-characters-of-a-string-to-print-out-using-pri)

Comment: `char s[] = "abcdef"; len = 3; start = 1; printf("%.*s", len, s + start);`

Comment: btw, for `getline` I'd prefer initializing `capacity` with `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I know how to work with a pointer to the beginning of a string, but I don't know how to determine the end.*

A pointer to the last character you'd like to print is a possible solution:

```
void vypis(const char *retezec, const char *end)
{   
    while (retezec <= end && *retezec != '\0')
    {
        putchar(*retezec);
        retezec++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main (void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
        
    getline(&str, &capacity, stdin);    
    vypis(str, str + 5);      //prints from str[0] to str[5]
    vypis(str + 1, str + 3);  //prints from str[1] to str[3]     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "abcdef";
    size_t pos = 1;
    int n = 3;
    
    printf( "%.*s\n", n, s + pos );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
bcd
```

Or another example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "abcdef";

    for ( int i = 0, n = ( int )strlen( s ); i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.*s\n", i + 1, s );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
```

You can write a generic function that can output a sub-string in any stream for example in an opened file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * print_substring( const char *s, size_t pos, size_t n, FILE * fp )
{
    size_t len = strlen( s );
    
    if ( pos < len )
    {
        if ( len - pos < n ) n = len - pos;
        
        fprintf( fp, "%.*s", ( int )n, s + pos );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "abcdef";

    for ( int i = 0, n = ( int )strlen( s ); i < n; i++ )
    {
        putc( '\n', print_substring( s, 0, i + 1, stdout ) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printSubString(const char *str, int start, int end) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (start >= length) {
        return;
    }
    if (end >= length) {
        return;
    }
    int index = start;
    while(index <= end) {
        printf("%c", str[index++]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char *str = "Hello, world!";
    printSubString(str, 3, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
lo, worl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily set the first character you don't want to print out (e in your example) to `\0`.

```
void vypis(char *retezec, size_t delka){
    char aux = retezec[delka];
    retezec[delka] = '\0';
    printf("%s", retezec);
    retezec[delka] = aux;
}
```

To make sure it also works on string literals and other `const char` pointers:

```
void vypis(const char* str, size_t delka){
    char aux = retezec[delka];
    char* retezec = (char*) str;
    retezec[delka] = '\0';
    printf("%s", retezec);
    retezec[delka] = aux;
}
```

Comment: Note, this won't work with string literals: `vypis("hello", 2);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Why you should never pass a string literal to a function accepting `char*` rather than `const char*`.

Comment: Thank you, I would just like to ask why you want to add 1 there, give the list one string more than I want?

Comment: @Aaron7 It is a bad solution because you are unable to use these functions with string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.