# Why fread() giving extra garbage value

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, fread

I am reading content of a file and and trying to print it, but it is giving extra garbage value.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    long length;
    char* content;
    FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    content = (char *)malloc(length);
    fread(content, 1, length, file);
    printf("%s\n", content);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Maybe I have to null terminate `content[length] = '\0';`?

The more `\n` newline characters the file has at the end, the more garbage I get.

Any solution, except using `calloc`?

Comment: Yes you have to null terminate `content`, `fread` won't do that for you, why would it, it's a binary input function, not a string processing function.

Comment: Try `malloc(length + 1)`, in order to allow for the null character at the end.

Comment: i am doing it content[length] = '\0' but its not working

Comment: That's outside the boundaries though. You could do `content[length - 1] = '\0'`, but that would truncate the last character out of your desired output of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is MSVC (clued by `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`) then the file mode is probably **text** by default, and all the CR-LF pairs will be shrunk to a single LF when you read it. Getting the file size does not take that into account. Use the number of characters *actually read* to terminate the string.

```
content = malloc(length + 1);           // room for terminator
size_t bytes = fread(content, 1, length, file);
content[bytes] = '\0';
```

Comment: Or, just open the file in binary mode instead: `fopen("text.txt", "rb")`

Comment: As for the [fread manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread), *The replacement has no effect on the file pointer or the return value.*

Comment: @273K, it does. I just read a file size `550` bytes, and `fread` reportedly read `536` bytes. The text file has 14 lines, and `536 + 14 = 550`.

Comment: So, the manual lies?

Comment: @273K, perhaps it does. The proof was eating the pudding. It makes no sense to do otherwise: or the caller does not know how many bytes are in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The file content does not end with the null char.
Your should reset the allocated memory buffer with 0, since it's unknown how many bytes will be read.

```
content = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
memset(content, 0, length + 1);
fread(content, 1, length, file);
```

Or you should set the data length while printing

```
length = fread(content, 1, length, file);
printf("%.*s\n", length, content);
```

See [Is there a way to specify how many characters of a string to print out using printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239519/is-there-a-way-to-specify-how-many-characters-of-a-string-to-print-out-using-pri)

Comment: Not working, the more \n at end of file more garbage value it gets

Comment: It's working. You might use another code. Ensure `file` is opened successfully.

Comment: *It's working.*  No, it's not.  Like the OP, you missed the text mode of the stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Please show the exact point where I missed it. I missed it in the second snipped, but updated it before your comment.